# How do I use % character in NSString stringWithFormat

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

How do I use the `%` character literal in an `NSString stringWithFormat`?

I am trying to do: `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%%@,%@",string1,string2];`

The first `%` does not show up.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%%%@,%@",string1,string2];
```

Answer (score 11):

Two percent charicters, %%, will print as one %.

From the [String Format Specifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html) list.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%%",str1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `%` two times (as escape character) should give you what you need. An example printing `%foo,bar` would look like this

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%%%@,%@", @"foo", @"bar"];
```