# Removes the special character from password in SoapRequest

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, soap

In My app I am using Soap request,

In that Soap request I need to Send Password to Authenticate,

My Password Contain Special Character,
              **ABC%1cf#+l6A98,D**

When I am sending the password with Soap request, It Removes **%** character from Password.

IN NSLOG, Password shows Like this  **ABC1cf#+l6A98,D**

So, On Soap request my Passsword going like this **ABC1cf#+l6A98,D**

How to set the **%** in Password Field,

How can i do that?

Comment: What does your NSLog line look like? Ie are you using a format string?

Comment: Does the `%` char reach your `SOAP` backend, or is it just in your `NSLog`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use % character in NSString stringWithFormat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9949908/how-do-i-use-character-in-nsstring-stringwithformat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Following Code before sending password to SOAP service :

```
NSString *outputString = [passwordString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%" withString:@"%%"];
```

Comment: Isn't this giving you a warning? Remove `NSString *` !

Comment: Thanks Devang its Working,If I written ABC%%1cf#+l6A98,D  than, It's takes the  ABC%1cf#+l6A98,D

Comment: @tipycalFlow : It is sample code. Why you think I need to remove `NSString *` ?

Comment: @Devang Since you've used `[passwordString stringByReplacing...`, it means `passwordString` has already been declared, right? Hence, in this line, you're declaring an `NSString` with a name that has already been used!